# Rook: Timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach/mount for pod

Tags: kubernetes, rook-storage

k8s version: v1.9
env: VirtualBox
os: Coreos

It is 1 node Kubernetes cluster
I followed the below steps:

1. Followed https://rook.io/docs/rook/v0.5/k8s-pre-reqs.html and updated the kubelet with

   Environment="RKT_OPTS=--volume modprobe,kind=host,source=/usr/sbin/modprobe \
     --mount volume=modprobe,target=/usr/sbin/modprobe \
     --volume lib-modules,kind=host,source=/lib/modules \
     --mount volume=lib-modules,target=/lib/modules \
     --uuid-file-save=/var/run/kubelet-pod.uuid"
2. Installed ceph utility

   rbd -v
   ceph version 10.2.2 (45107e21c568dd033c2f0a3107dec8f0b0e58374)

All rook pods are working but MySQL pod fails with error 'timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach/mount for pod'

```
➜  kubectl get pod -n rook-system
NAME                             READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
rook-agent-rqw6j                 1/1       Running   0          21m
rook-operator-5457d48c94-bhh2z   1/1       Running   0          22m
➜   kubectl get pod -n rook
NAME                             READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
rook-api-848df956bf-fhmg2        1/1       Running   0          20m
rook-ceph-mgr0-cfccfd6b8-8brxz   1/1       Running   0          20m
rook-ceph-mon0-xdd77             1/1       Running   0          21m
rook-ceph-mon1-gntgh             1/1       Running   0          20m
rook-ceph-mon2-srmg8             1/1       Running   0          20m
rook-ceph-osd-84wmn              1/1       Running   0          20m
➜   kubectl get pv
NAME                                       CAPACITY   ACCESSMODES   RECLAIMPOLICY   STATUS    CLAIM                    STORAGECLASS   REASON    AGE
pvc-6a4c5c2a-127d-11e8-a846-080027b424ef   20Gi       RWO           Delete          Bound     default/mysql-pv-claim   rook-block               15m
➜  kubectl get pvc
NAME             STATUS    VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESSMODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
mysql-pv-claim   Bound     pvc-6a4c5c2a-127d-11e8-a846-080027b424ef   20Gi       RWO           rook-block     15m
kubectl get pods
NAME                               READY     STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
wordpress-mysql-557ffc4f69-8zxsq   0/1       ContainerCreating   0          16m


Error when I describe pod : FailedMount Unable to mount volumes for pod "wordpress-mysql-557ffc4f69-8zxsq_default(6a932df1-127d-11e8-a846-080027b424ef)": timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach/mount for pod "default"/"wordpress-mysql-557ffc4f69-8zxsq". list of unattached/unmounted volumes=[mysql-persistent-storage]
```

Also added the following option to rook-operator.yaml

```
- name: FLEXVOLUME_DIR_PATH
  value: "/var/lib/kubelet/volumeplugins"
```

Could you please help with this? Please let me know if you need further details. I checked the similar issues but a solution is not working.

Comment: Have you looked at the kubelet log?

Comment: yes. It was giving 'No volume plugin matched' error. I could have pasted the log but I destroyed it few hours back. I will put the log by recreating the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using cephfs or rbd volumes as a backend to Ceph? Here are some things to check:

1. Please confirm that your Pod can communicate with ceph cluster well, this looks like an issue with the communication to the ceph volumes you’re trying to use.
2. Check that your Ceph volume plugins are set correctly.
3. What’s the state of `# kubectl get pv`?
4. Take a look at your persistent volumes and claims.
5. You could also try the Root.io tool, they have good integration with Ceph object storage.